# Ошибка с SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

выскакивает вот такая ошибка(все логи не копировал, только самые первые)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dimantik.myapplication, PID: 19084
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1193)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1064)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1232)
    at com.example.dimantik.myapplication.ShowCategoryTaskFragment.getTaskNames(ShowCategoryTaskFragment.java:80)
    at com.example.dimantik.myapplication.ShowCategoryTaskFragment.onStart(ShowCategoryTaskFragment.java:51)
```

Вот на что ругается

```
public String[] getTaskNames(){
    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper = new TaskOpenHelper(getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("TASK1",
            new String[]{"NAME"},
            "CATEGORY = ?",
            new String[]{category},
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0){
        return new String[0];
    }else {
        String[] taskNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        String names = "";
        do {
            names = names + cursor.getString(0);
            taskNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
            i++;
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        return taskNames;
    }
}
```

Ругается именно на инициализацию курсора

Comment: А `category` точно не `null`?..

Answer (score 1):

Проверь место где ты инициализируеш `category`. Похоже что в тот момент когда ты вызываешь `query`, `category == null`.
Если ты хочешь чтобы `category` могла принимать значение `null`, нужно сделать следующее:

```
String tableName = "TASK1";
String[] columns = {"NAME"};
String whereNotNull = "CATEGORY = ?";
String whereNull = "CATEGORY IS NULL";
String[] whereArgs = { category };

Cursor cursor = whereArgs == null ?
     db.query(tableName, columns, whereNull, null, null, null, null) :
     db.query(tableName, columns, whereNotNull, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = names + cursor.getString(0);
taskNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
```

Пробовал 0 заменить на `i`? Ты же вроде данные из курсора по позиции пытаешься вытянуть.